# Need help extracting data from a corrupt file

Tags: sqlite, adobe, extract, photoshop, lightroom

I have a file located at the following location on my computer:
`D:\Pictures\Imported Catalogue\Ojulari-2`

I want to be able to extract the data from the (corrupt file) database file into a text file with all the SQL commands needed to recreate the database.

I'm following instructions from the following link, but I seem to be stuck executing the right command line or should I say navigation the the location of the corrupt file using the command line provided (See below)

Link to instructions I am following: http://gerhardstrasse.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/recover-from-a-corrupt-adobe-lightroom-catalog-file/

Command line I am trying to execute:

```
echo .dump | ./sqlite3 ~/lightroom_catalog.lrcat > ~/lightroom_catalog.sql
```

Comment: In Unix OSes, `~` is a shorthand for the home directory, and `/` is the directory separator. You might want to adjust that for Windows.

Comment: No luck at all. i will really appreciate if you can help me with the correct syntax? I forgot to back up my files and a days work of photo editing really depends on this fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. [Download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) the `sqlite3` command-line shell, and put the .exe file in the same directory as the database.
2. Open a Windows command-line shell, and go to that directory:

   ```
   D:
   cd "\Pictures\Imported Catalogue\Ojulari-2"
   ```
3. Execute:

   ```
   sqlite3 MyDatabaseFile .dump > MyDatabase.sql
   ```